# Calculate sum of 2 inputs dynamically - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I have 2 simple input and a div that should display the sum :

I would like the result to be dynamic, so everytime I change the number, the result update.

I tried to set an array `let numbers = []`, and push the data once change. But it pushes new data, instead or erasing it.

```js
let ssP = document.getElementById('ss-p')
let pc = document.getElementById('pc')
let rc1 = document.getElementById('rc1')

let numbers = []

ssP.addEventListener('change', () => {
    numbers.push(ssP.value)
    console.log(numbers)
})

pc.addEventListener('change', () => {
    numbers.push(pc.value)
    console.log(numbers)
})
```

```html
<div>
   <label for="ss-p">Remboursement de la sécurité sociale (en %) :</label>
   <input type="text" id="ss-p" name="ss-p">
</div>

<div>
   <label for="pc">Prix de la consultation (en €) :</label>
   <input type="text" id="pc" name="pc">
</div>

<div>
   <p for="rc1">Reste à charge (100%) :</p>
   <div id="rc1"></div>
</div>
```

Any help ?

Comment: What does your javascript code look like?

Comment: Setup `input` event listeners on the two input fields, which triggers a common function that calculates the sum and outputs it.

Comment: @duncan I edited my post with my javascript code

Comment: @Terry ok, gonna try it !

Comment: You don't need an array; just select the dive on each change (using DOM), then change it's `innerHTML` to sum of the the inputs (which you also obtain using DOM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<html>
       <head>
       <script>
     function calculateSum(){
     var val_1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("ss-p").value===""?0:document.getElementById("ss-p").value);
     var val_2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("pc").value===""?0:document.getElementById("pc").value);
        document.getElementById("rc1").innerText = val_1 + val_2;
     }
        
       </script>
       </head>
       <body onload="onload();">
            <div>
   <label for="ss-p">Remboursement de la sécurité sociale (en %) :</label>
   <input type="text" id="ss-p" name="ss-p"  onkeyup="calculateSum()">
</div>

<div>
   <label for="pc">Prix de la consultation (en €) :</label>
   <input type="text" id="pc" name="pc" onkeyup="calculateSum()">
</div>

<div>
   <p for="rc1">Reste à charge (100%) :</p>
   <div id="rc1"></div>
</div>
       </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: if working then accept and upvote so that it can help others.

Comment: Yes, I have to wait 4 minutes and i'll do. Thanks again